# std::unique_ptr use of deleted function with move

Tags: c++

there is the following code:

```
struct RenderableAtmosphere {
    std::unique_ptr<Atmosphere> atmosphere;
    float hScaleFactor, parentEarthSizeCoefficient;
    bool isUseToneMapping = false;
};
    
struct RenderableSceneComponent {
    ...
    std::vector<RenderableAtmosphere> atmospheres;
};
    
...
RenderableSceneComponent uranusSystemComponent;
    
uranusSystemComponent.atmospheres = vector<RenderableAtmosphere>{move(renderableUranusAtmosphere)};
//uranusSystemComponent.atmospheres.push_back(move(renderableUranusAtmosphere));
```

In the case of a move assignment operator call, the code does not compile with the following set of errors:

```
In file included from D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/vector:62,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Auxiliary_Modules/Camera.h:5,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Auxiliary_Modules/AuxiliaryModules.h:4,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Application.h:3,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Application.cpp:1:
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = RenderableAtmosphere; _Args = {const RenderableAtmosphere&}]':
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _ForwardIterator = RenderableAtmosphere*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _ForwardIterator = RenderableAtmosphere*]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _ForwardIterator = RenderableAtmosphere*; _Tp = RenderableAtmosphere]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1464:33:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _Tp = RenderableAtmosphere; _Alloc = std::allocator<RenderableAtmosphere>]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:519:2:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = RenderableAtmosphere; _Alloc = std::allocator<RenderableAtmosphere>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<RenderableAtmosphere>]'
D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Application.cpp:888:102:   required from here
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'RenderableAtmosphere::RenderableAtmosphere(const RenderableAtmosphere&)'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

I cannot figure out at what point a copy of the class is called, which tries to call the deleted copy constructor on `unique_ptr`. But if you use `push_back`, then everything works.

Comment: `std::initializer_list`, which `std::vector` constructor uses as a parameter, stores const elements, so you can't move from it. Use `.push_back()` to add `renderableUranusAtmosphere`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, damn, man, you're right! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The statement

```
uranusSystemComponent.atmospheres = vector<RenderableAtmosphere>{move(renderableUranusAtmosphere)};
```

calls the assignment operator of vector:

```
vector& operator=( const vector& other );
```

which requires a copy constructor for `RenderableAtmosphere` with the signature:

```
RenderableAtmosphere::RenderableAtmosphere(const RenderableAtmosphere&)
```

But `RenderableAtmosphere` does not have such a copy constructor since it has a `std::unique_ptr` member. [Copy Constructors on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

That's the reason why you get these error messages.

Comment: No! This calls the move assignment operator for the temporary vector. The problem here is still when creating this temporary vector (I checked), `HolyBlackCat` is right, the problem is in the `initializer_list`, the objects in which are constant, which makes it impossible to move from it.